# changing CSS value with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

When my adapted-for-no-javascript page loads, one of the styles loaded is this:

```
//accordion open
.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

That way my accordion is all open and the content is visible for users without javascript.

But when a user that has javascript enabled visits the site, I would like the value to be changed automatically like this:

```
//accordion collapsed
.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
    max-height: 0;
}
```

How do I best do that with jQuery?

This is probably quite elementary but I am new to jquery/JS and get a bit lost googling for solutions because all search hits seem to apply to much more complicated cases.

Comment: What is the purpose of `swap` tag? `This is probably quite elementary but I am new to jquery/JS and get a bit lost googling for solutions because all search hits seem to apply to much more complicated cases.` Your research should have bring you to relevant `css()` method, here is the DOC: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing or injecting css, I suggest adding a `no-js` class to the body/html/container and then removing it with jquery.

Your css will look like this

```
.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
    max-height: 0;
}

.no-js .accordionItemCollapsed, .no-js .accordionItem.is-collapsed {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The jquery is very straightforward

```
$('html').removeClass('no-js');
```

This approach is much more efficient than querying the dom for all accordions and then changing the style property of every element.

In addition to that, this can be reused for other parts of the website where you need to have different styling for when js is not available.

Comment: If you add this class to the HTML element you can place the remove class script in the head section and not wrap it inside document.ready event. Takes care of FOUC issues.

Comment: @dogoku @salman Great, it works! However, I noticed something peculiar. I am using wordpress, so I put the line of jQuery in a file of it's own (since it should go in the header), and enqueue it correctly as a dependency of jQuery. When that file contains only `$('html').removeClass('no-js');` I get no FOUC. But when I try with `jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('html').removeClass('no-js');
});` (because I initially thought I needed a function) I get roughly ½ second of FOUC. Is this normal? Does wrapping it as a function make it that much slower to execute?

Comment: @pastic `jQuery(function(){})` fires after the document and synchronous JavaScript has been downloaded. Browser could start displaying the document earlier and thus the FOUC issue. For HTML element you can safely omit document ready since HTML is the first element in the document and by the time browser reads the head tag it is guaranteed that it has seen the HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the class definition. If you want to change the properties of element:

```
$('.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed').css('max-height', 0);
```

> Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2

If you want to overwrite the properties of the all elements(**Not Recommended**):

```
$('body').append('<style>.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed { max-height: 0; } </style>');
```

I'll suggest you should shoud take advantage of `open/close` events of accordion:

```
// accordion open event callback
$('.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed').css('max-height', '100%');

// accordion close event callback
$('.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed').css('max-height', 0);
```

Comment: Down-Voters add comments here, why you have down-voted

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed').css('max-height', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need jQuery for that task, it would add unnecessary overhead to your application.

simply use the following code, it will only be executed if the visitor has javascript enabled anyway.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("accordionItemCollapsed accordionItem.is-collapsed").style.maxWidth = "0px";
```

Comment: Whether I put it in the <head> or just before the </body>, I can't get it to work. This is the snippet I use: `<script>document.getElementsByClassName("accordionItemCollapsed accordionItem.is-collapsed").style.maxHeight = "0px";</script>`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('.accordionItemCollapsed, .accordionItem.is-collapsed').css('max-height', 0);
```

css method takes two parameters, first the style property in your case `max-height` and second the value in your case `0`.